# EU student NOT applying to EU Settlement Scheme

Tags: immigration, eu-citizens, students, brexit, eu-settlement-scheme

I'm EU studying in the UK. I think expatriates is the most suitable StackExchange for my question, and I tried to add some meaningful tags: please suggest moving to another StackExchange website or suggest other tags, need there be!

Suppose that I won't apply to the EU Settlement Scheme.

OPTION 1: I finish coursework by 29 June 2021.

A. I stay in the UK: is staying in the UK problematic? Also, my course might drag for some time after my last submission because of administrative reasons: in this case I suppose that I would keep being (at least officially) a student in the UK, is this problematic?

B. I leave the UK: my course might drag for some time after my last submission because of administrative reasons: in this case I suppose that I would keep being (at least officially) a student in the UK, however physically abroad, is this problematic?

OPTION 2: I finish coursework after 1 July 2021.

A. I stay in the UK (and I will definitely still be a student enrolled in a UK university): is this problematic?

B. I leave the UK (and I will definitely still be a student enrolled in a UK university, but living abroad): is this problematic?
Also, I might need to be physically present in the UK for submitting some documents before finishing my course: would I be able to satisfy this requirement?

NOTE: Citizens from many countries don’t need a visa to come to the UK and study for six months or less. However this might be already accounted for (31 December 2020 + six months = 31 June 2021).

Comment: It's at least going to be least expensive for you to apply under the settlement scheme, since it is free of charge.  I'll try to post an answer on Monday or Tuesday if a suitable one doesn't appear before then.  But your note is, I think, incorrect: for a formal course of study, I believe even those who may visit without a visitor visa need to have a student visa.